# How to check which admin user has added the products in admin backend magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, product, user-roles, user, add

I have multi websites site. I have multiple users with different user roles. Is there any way to save and check which admin user has added the product in admin panel backend.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Its not possible to track which Admin user added the Products. There are two way to achive this:

1. Third Part Extension: You can use Advanced Permission Third Party extension that provide this feature and many other features as well.
2. Customization: Create One Product attribute Or Field in `Catalog_Product_entity` table While Saving the Product from backend Create Observer for event `catalog_product_save_before` to save logged in user Id OR user name with Product If its creating OR updating as per requirement.

Comment: Thank u. Where can i get this event catalog_product_save_before???

Comment: I got that. Can u tell me how can i store the details if i am using custom attribute

Comment: here is one example .. same way you can set values in Product 
https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-new-observer-on-trigger-of-magento-2-event-catalog_product_save_before/

Comment: Sorry didn;t get that. I did not find it relative to my requirements.

Comment: Create a table for admin log and add event after each controller to track the log of admin user either it is save, edit or view for all modules not only for product.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a custom attribute called : "updated_by" from magento backend and don't forget to drag that into default attribute set otherwise it will not work!!

Add events.xml file to vendor/module/etc/adminhtml/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="observer_name" instance="vendor\module\Observer\ProductSaveAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Add ProductSaveAfter.php at vendor/module/Observer/

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class ProductSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $instance = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $productId = (int) $observer->getProduct()->getId();
        $user = $instance->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session')->getUser()->getUsername();
        $action = $instance->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action');
        $action->updateAttributes([$productId], array('updated_by' => $user), 0);
    }
}
```